# Elegant way to slice a list with a condition

Tags: python, list

Given a list [2,8,13,15,24,30], all the elements of which are supposed to be in range(31). Now I want to slice it into 3 lists, first list with numbers from 0 to 10, the second one with numbers from 11 to 20, and the others into the rest.

Here is my ugly code :

```
numbers = [2,8,13,15,24,30]
mylist = [[],[],[]] # I hate this the most...
for i in numbers:
    if i <= 10 :
        mylist[0].append(i)
    elif i > 10 and i <= 20:
        mylist[1].append(i)
    else:
        mylist[2].append(i)

print mylist
```

I don't think this is a good way to do it. Any suggestions please?

Comment: draw an abstraction. e.g.: list + 2 predicate functions. later you can fix the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input is sorted you can do this in one pass with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

[list(g) for _,g in groupby(numbers, lambda x: x//10)]
Out[3]: [[2, 8], [13, 15], [24, 26]]
```

No need to initialize a bunch of lists this way, `groupby` yields them on the fly.

This may be off-by-one in terms of how you wanted to treat the modulo-10 boundaries; if it's unclear you can always define your own `grouper` function:

```
def grouper(x):
    '''bins matching the semantics:
    [0,10] (10,20] (20, 30]'''
    return (x-1)//10 if x > 0 else 0
```

and use it thusly:

```
numbers = [2,8,13,15,24,30]

[list(g) for _,g in groupby(numbers, grouper)]
Out[5]: [[2, 8], [13, 15], [24, 30]]
```

Comment: think that this would have been better if it preserved the original logic, eg. lambda x: 1 if x<11 else 2 if x<21 else 3  but groupby seems like the right choice here

Comment: seems that `x//10` excludes 30 to another list. But upvoted for the brilliant idea of groupby.

Answer (score 1):

Without rethinking your basic approach, you can do:

```
for n in numbers:
    mylist[n//10].append(n)
```

This takes advantage of integer division, e.g. `19//10` = 1.

There are much more elegant ways to do this using other Python constructs; I will make a second answer for those.  But for now this is a quick, easy and not too nauseating way to do what you want.

Comment: ugly hack. and BTW 30/10 = 3. oops.

Comment: Don't use the `/` operator for integer division, as it's incompatible with Python 3. I haven't used it in a while, but as far as I know the `//` integer division operator has been backported to 2.x, so it's better to use that for clarity.

Comment: Roger -- agreed, changed above.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filterList(original, lower, upper):
    return filter(lambda i : i > lower and i <= upper, original)
```

This can be called like so

```
firstSlice = filterList(numbers, 0, 10)
>>> firstSlice
[2, 8]
```

Making your range list

```
ranges = [0, 10, 20, 30]
```

Then making the 2D list in list comprehension

```
>>> [filterList(numbers, ranges[i], ranges[i+1]) for i in range(len(ranges)-1)]
[[2, 8], [13, 15], [24, 26]]
```

Comment: I thought about filter, but didn't make it here. In this way I can specify any boundries. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about using `reduce` ?

```
numbers = [2,8,13,15,24,26]

def part(acc, x):
    #  first list with numbers from 0 to 10, 
    #  the second one with numbers from 11 to 20,
    #  and the others into the rest.
    #
    #  This is *not* the same as:
    #    acc[x/10].append(x)
    #
    if x < 10:
        acc[0].append(x)
    elif x > 20:
        acc[2].append(x)
    else:
        acc[1].append(x)
    return acc

print reduce(part, numbers, [[],[],[]])
```

---

And to remove the hated `[[],[],[]]`, if you can live with a dictionary instead of a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
numbers = [2,8,13,15,24,26]

def part(acc, x):
    if x < 10:
        acc[0].append(x)
    elif x > 20:
        acc[2].append(x)
    else:
        acc[1].append(x)
    return acc

print reduce(part, numbers, defaultdict(list))
```

Producing:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [2, 8], 1: [13, 15], 2: [24, 26]})
```

Answer (score 1):

One nicer way to do this uses default dicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(list)
for n in numbers:
    output[n//10].append(n)
```

This creates a dict with a default element (if you access a key that hasn't been created) being an empty list.  You don't need to create the empty list-of-lists you didn't like in your original code sample.

You can then access the output by decade, i.e. while `output` is a dict, `output[0]` is a list.

If you need to preserve your original output logic, converting this dict to a list-of-lists is simple.

Comment: First time to know defaultlist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what counts for *elegant*, but list comprehensions shoudl work:

```
numbers = [2,8,13,15,24,26]
mylist = []
mylist.append([x for x in numbers if x <=10])
mylist.append([x for x in numbers if x > 10 and x <= 20])
mylist.append([x for x in numbers if x > 2 ])
print mylist
```

Comment: No need to do as appends can just do mylist = [ [...], [...], [...] ]

Comment: @TylerEaves, right except the OP seemed to say he he hated that part the most. That would make it shorter, but also probably more difficult to read.